# How do I display html encoded values in svg?

Tags: html, encoding, svg, d3.js, html-encode

I am using d3 to generate svg and end up with markup similar to the following:

```
<text class="rule" text-anchor="middle">&amp;pound;10K</text>
```

Compare to similar html that renders as expected.

```
<div>
    &pound;20,160 - &pound;48,069
</div>
```

Is there a property I need to set on the svg tag to get a similar type of encoding? I tried adding a meta tag to the page `<meta name="content" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />` but this did not work.

Answer (score 8):

HTML entities are not defined in SVG. You can either use the actual unicode character or use the [`foreignObject` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to embed HTML into your SVG.

Comment: It is also possible to use character references like `&#163;` or `&#xa3;` (for “£”), since they work in all XML-based languages.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using d3js, you can use the unicode as well.

Example to append text to span:

```
svg.append('span')
   .text('Pound: ' + '\u00A3' + ' or ' + '\uFFE1');
```