# D3 append HTML not working in edge browser

Tags: d3.js, svg, microsoft-edge

I have a chart created using d3 that I need to use some HTML inside of which works fine in Chrome but edge does not display the HTML and I don't know why.

[Here is a JSFiddle that shows the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/c8c6fuhw/1/), works in Chrome does not in edge..

Here is the code in fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function(d3) {
    'use strict';

    var dataset = [
      { label: 'Abulia', count: 10 }, 
      { label: 'Betelgeuse', count: 20 },
      { label: 'Cantaloupe', count: 30 },
      { label: 'Dijkstra', count: 40 }
    ];

    var width = 360;
    var height = 360;
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category20b();

    var svg = d3.select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + 
        ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
      .sort(null);

    var path = svg.selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(dataset))
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
        return color(d.data.label);
      });
         svg.append("text")
            .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('x', 100)
        .data(['some text'])
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr('font-size', '20px')
        .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
        .attr('fill', 'white')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d; 
        });
    svg.append("text")
    .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('x', -100)
        .data(['some html &deg;'])
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr('font-size', '20px')
        .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
        .attr('fill', 'white')
        .html(function(d) {
            return d; 
        });
  })(window.d3);


  </script>
</body>
```

I have also tried:

```
 svg.append("foreignObject")
    .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('x', -100)
        .data(['some html &deg;'])
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr('font-size', '20px')
        .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
        .attr('fill', 'white')
                  .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
        .html(function(d) {
            return d; 
        });
```

[As per Q/A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946604/insert-html-code-inside-svg-text-element)

Comment: Confirmed. Edge don't render .html. I can see it on Opera and Chrome but not on Edge (25) neither IE (11), IE (9)

Comment: Frustrating :-( I need to support edge and I also need to put in a degrees sign as in that sample...

Comment: You can use an SVG symbol ref. First define your symbol (a circle reensambling degrees sign) and use it as you need

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that! Thank you! Do you think I should answer my own question in that its not possible to do what I was trying to do in edge?  I cant find any evidence (other than experience) to prove that edge does not support this

Comment: Sure. Do it, someone else would find useful your discovery and the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors actually breaking the output of the text containing the degree sign. The first one is the use of [`selection.html()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#html) which is not to be used for SVG content:

> Note: as its name suggests, selection.html is only supported on HTML elements. SVG elements and other non-HTML elements do not support the innerHTML property, and thus are incompatible with selection.html.

I suppose you chose that method because you wanted to insert an HTML entity, namely the degree sign. For reasons explained below this can be achieved by other means and the method in use can be changed to `.text()` to work with SVG content.

The second error is the use of an HTML entity (`&deg;`) which is [not defined for SVGs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473406/4235784). As an alternative, you can use the [Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Unicode_escape_sequences) `\u00b0` for your degree sign.

```
svg.append("text")
  // ...
  .data(['some html \u00b0'])  // Use Unicode escape sequence instead of HTML entity
  // ... .attr("", "")
  .text(function(d) {          // Use .text() instead of .html()
    return d;
  });
```

Have a look at the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0f4cwsy/).

---

Your initial approach should actually work in no browser at all, because it is based on improper fiddling with DOM nodes. However, Chrome, FF and some others seem to be a bit more relaxed about it, while IE got it right.

Comment: Thank you, I have already implemented a different approach but have just changed it to use this now. I did indeed try to use the unicode but I'm not sure what I did wrong because I failed to get that to work. Thanks for you help!

Comment: The documentation you cite is wrong now (though it was correct at the time it was written). People kept trying to create SVG via html() so the html specification was changed to make this work and most browsers followed suit. Edge still has not but presumably will at some point.

Comment: @RobertLongson Interesting! Always a delight to read your up-to-date information about any progress in the specs! I am a bit confused, though: what has the use of `innerHTML´ on SVG content got to do with the HTML spec? Do you have any reference to the changes of the spec? I just bashed another user for doing it wrong; I may have to backpedal then.

Comment: InnerHtml is a property on Element, SVG and HTML are both Elements. HTML tends to be in charge of common parts as there's masses more html content.

Comment: Just an addendum to this answer, which is 2 years old: according to Amelia Bellamy-Royds, most of modern browsers support `innerHTML` for SVG: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=yWU6DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false. In fact, I just recently wrote an answer using `selection.html()` for an SVG: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905093/5768908

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Have you read the above comments by Robert Longson? He said basically *that* two years ago. Always nice to learn from his comments!

Comment: @altocumulus No, I didn't read the comment, I just read the answer and thought about writing this addendum. In that case, why didn't you edit your answer?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Why? Hm, one of the great unsolved mysteries of humankind. I remember being totally baffled and dumbfounded by his comments because I always took for granted what I had just written. I guess it took me so long to recover that I had forgotten about it by then ;-) I will give it a second thought and revise this answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not supported in Edge. I cannot find any documentation or other commentary with a rudimentary Google Search.

For my case what I ended up doing it just adding a two circles on top of each-other to make the symbol I needed.

```
    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", degreeSignOffsetX)
        .attr("cy", degreeSignOffsetY)
        .attr("r", 2)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return 'black'; });

    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", degreeSignOffsetX)
        .attr("cy", degreeSignOffsetY)
        .attr("r", 1)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return 'white'; });
```

There might be a better solution using a symbol but this worked for me and it meets my requirements.

If some one else has any info on why or if edge CAN do this and I am missing something feel free to answer and I will accept the answer