# insert svg string element into an existing svg tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, d3.js, svg

I have an existing `<svg></svg>`, and I would like to append an `svg` element, which is a string.
Example:

```
var svg_string = '<g><text x="100" y="100">Hello</text></g>';

d3.select('svg').append(svg_string); // or something like that
```

Can I do that ? Without using `d3.xml`, because I don't want to load a svg file from somewhere.

And I've tried with jQuery by doing this.

```
$('svg').append('<svg><g><text></text></g></svg>')
```

But I would like to know if there is a better way, without appending svg tag

UPDATE: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear.

I would like to append the `svg_string` into a svg element like

```
<svg><g id="test"></g></svg>

$('#test').append(svg_string)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct practice is to declare each attribute or node explicitly.

```
d3.select('svg').append("g").append("text").attr("x",100).attr("y",100).text("Hello");
```

If you really want to add html string then use :

```
d3.select('svg').html("<g><text x=\"100\" y=\"100\">Hello</text></g>");
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/ero38b49/

EDIT : Based on question update :

If you wish to add string `str` inside `<g>` with `id` "test"

```
  var str = "<g><text x=\"100\" y=\"100\">Hello</text></g>";
    d3.select('#test').html(str);
```

This would give you :

```
<svg>
   <g id="test">
      <g><text y="100" x="100">Hello</text>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/ero38b49/1/

If you wish to `append` string `str` to`<svg>` ( as a sibling of `<g>` with `id` "test" )

```
d3.select("svg").html(d3.select("svg").html() + str);
```

This would give you :

```
<svg>
  <g id="test"/>
  <g><text y="100" x="100">Hello</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/ero38b49/2/

Comment: I knew how to do with this method, but I want to append with the string. By doing that, it forces me to parse each tag and theirs attributes, a little bit complicate :/

Comment: Updated the answer. I would still recommend using separate notations

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: Note that modifying the innerHTML will remove all event listeners attached to your element and its siblings. One should prefer to use a DOMParser (requires a complete document string though) and the `appendChild()` method.

Comment: @03t02 The first two lines of this answer are correct, the rest is making wrong use of `selection.html()`. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38072166/4235784) to another question for further explanations. For the time being this will work in Chrome and FF, but it will break in IE. Furthermore, it is against the standard, which doesn't allow the use of `innerHTML` for SVG content. This could break anytime soon.

Comment: @Kaiido: What you mentioned about the event listener is true. However, like i mentioned in the first statement, the correct way is to use separate notations. The answer was provided for what was requested.

Comment: Then it is just the correct way to declare elements from the d3 library, but the correct way to parse a string containng xml  html or svg, is the use of a DOMParser. Which is the question here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<svg><g id = 'svg-element'></g></svg>
<script>
  var svg_string = '<g><text x="100" y="100">Hello</text></g>';
  document.getElementById('svg-element').parentNode.innerHTML += svg_string;
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this method is you can't insert the svg_string with a svg element. If I have an ID which is a svg element, this method doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This code works fine for me; it adds the text onto the end of the svg element.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. What I want to say is, in this case:

<svg><g id="test"></g></svg>

document.getElementById('test')

Your method doen'st work

Comment: I updated it. You can just get the parent of the g element and add the string to it.