# How to prevent SVG text from flowing out of its circle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This is how the text is displaying inside the circle now:

[image]

This is how I would like to display the text inside the circle:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to cut off / hide / or? the part of the text that doesn't fit inside the circle and show three dots at the end of these too-long-texts. I've found many answers that explained how to wrap multiple words in a circle, but I couldn't find a way to fit one too-long word in a circle in this way.

These are the styles added to the circles and texts when they are entered:

```
enterNode = (selection) => {
        selection.select('circle')
            .attr("r", 30)
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.label)
            })
            .style("stroke", "#4D5061")

        selection.select('text')
            .style("fill", "#3D3B30")
            .style("font-weight", "600")
            .style("text-transform", "uppercase")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
    }
```

The circles are part of a d3 force layout displayed in this way

```
<svg>
  <g class="node-group">
    <g class="node>
      <circle class="circle"></circle>
      <text class="text"></text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g class="link-group">...</g>
</svg>
```

I would really appreaciate it if you have an idea on how to fix this!

Comment: I can think of a horribly hacky way to do it, if you want to know.

Comment: sure, why not. All the help is really appreciated

Comment: Yep, @Andrew I think the same, you need to make some math XD

Comment: @Vincent I did something similar, let me search if I can find the code

Comment: @Vincent I don't know if it's what's you looking for, but I change the font size according the radius of the circle `let fontSize = Math.max(10, Math.min(17, Math.floor(Math.sqrt(radius) * 1.9)))`, this is between 10 and 17, but you can play with this example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a D3 based solution for SVG elements, since you have an SVG with a D3 force directed graph.

It involves getting the circle's width (which you can do using `attr("r")` as a getter, but here I'm using `getBBox()`) and the text's length (here I'm using `getComputedTextLength()`) and passing those values to a custom function.

First, let's see the circle and the text without any function. This is the text in my demo:

> This above all: to thine own self be true, And it must follow, as the night the day, Thou canst not then be false to any man.

As you can see, it's not only longer than the circle, it's actually bigger than the SVG:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 200)
  .attr("cy", 110)
  .attr("r", 100)
  .style("fill", "powderblue")
  .style("stroke", "darkslategray");

var text = svg.append("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("dominant-baseline", "central")
  .attr("x", 200)
  .attr("y", 110)
  .text("This above all: to thine own self be true, And it must follow, as the night the day, Thou canst not then be false to any man.");
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="220"></svg>
```

Now let's call our function, here named `crop()`. It has to be called on the text selection, using the circle selection as the second argument, like this:

```
text.call(crop, circle);
```

And this is the function:

```
function crop(text, circle) {
    var circleRadius = circle.node().getBBox().width;
    while (text.node().getComputedTextLength() > circleRadius) {
        text.text(text.text().slice(0, -4) + "...");
    }
};
```

As you can see, it basically takes the values and, in a `while` loop, crops the text (with the `"..."`) until it fits the space. I'm actually printing the text again at every loop, to get the computed length of the node... however, those modern browsers are so insanely fast that one can't notice.

And here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 200)
  .attr("cy", 110)
  .attr("r", 100)
  .style("fill", "powderblue")
  .style("stroke", "darkslategray");

var text = svg.append("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("dominant-baseline", "central")
  .attr("x", 200)
  .attr("y", 110)
  .text("This above all: to thine own self be true, And it must follow, as the night the day, Thou canst not then be false to any man.");

text.call(crop, circle);

function crop(text, circle) {
  var circleRadius = circle.node().getBBox().width;
  while (text.node().getComputedTextLength() > circleRadius) {
    text.text(text.text().slice(0, -4) + "...");
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="220"></svg>
```

Comment: I like your answer a lot more than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want something similar to this...
Where the text is restricted by the fact it can't draw outside the container of the SVG, so you'll just nest a SVG inside a SVG

```html
<svg width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3"></circle>
  <svg width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 52 52" x="13" y="15.5">
    <g x="0" y="25">
      <text x="0" y="27">TEXasT</text>
    </g>
  <svg>
</svg>
```

EDIT:
O.P wanted ellipsis so this is the new fiddle.
It uses absolute positioning and transforms to ALWAYS CENTER the inner text both vertically and horizontally.

```css
#p {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
#c {
  width: 112px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3"></circle>
    <div id="c">
      BLAHAHAHHAasdsadsadas
    </div>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is adding the `...` at the end when hitting that condition

Comment: Hmmm give me a second

Comment: The problem with yours is that it never checks to see if the word fits within the `svg` element. You're adding `...` in every situation. You need JavaScript for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the DOM element with that `className` and change the `innerText` to whatever you want. Then set a `maxWidth`. My function adds that text to the DOM and then checks to see if the length of the DOM element, with the `innerText` in it, is too large. If it's smaller, then do nothing, but if it's larger, start using `slice` on the string and taking away trailing characters and adding the `...` as well. Rinse and repeat.

I have a `setTimeout` to show both situations and prove that it works.

Make sure you're using css that will actually change the width of the html element based on the text inside it, or it will run forever and freeze your browser. That's why I use `display: flex`

```js
function reduceWord(className, innerText, maxWidth) {
  let textElement = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0] //assuming only one html element named that class
  textElement.innerHTML = innerText
  if (textElement.offsetWidth > maxWidth) {
    let nextInnerText
    while (textElement.offsetWidth > maxWidth) {
      nextInnerText = textElement.innerHTML
      textElement.innerHTML = nextInnerText.slice(0, nextInnerText.length - 4) + '...'
    }
  }
}

reduceWord('example', 'Programming', 100)

setTimeout(() => reduceWord('example', 'Programming', 50), 5000)
```

```css
.container {
display: flex;
}

.example {
border: 1px solid black;
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="example"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an SVG: unfortunately there is no `innerHTML` here. OP cannot use this code.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You can't manually add `innerHTML` into the `text` tag? Does that mean the rendered text is an attribute of the `text` tag element?

Comment: No, you can't. SVG is not HTML. This will have no effect: `textElement.innerHTML`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Maybe we're not on the same wavelength, but `svg` is part of the html5 standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5. You can modify it with vanilla JavaScript, but you are correct about `innerHTML`. You can't use it the way I did. My mistake

Comment: edit: I lied. I see a lot of delination between the concept of `SVG` and `HTML` in the docs. It's just that it can be embedded easily.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado *"This is an SVG: unfortunately there is no innerHTML here."* That is not correct; at least, not any more. I was once [corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064765/d3-append-html-not-working-in-edge-browser/38067014#comment65337445_38072166) by Robert Longson on this topic. And, indeed, `d3.select("body").append("svg").node().innerHTML = '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"/>';` works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wnysrpoa/.

Comment: @altocumulus not for what the answer wants to do here.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I know, I know... It was meant as side note addressed to you. Read the comment literally stripped off of this answer's context.

Comment: @altocumulus Ok, I see... thanks for the info. I'm having some nice ideas already...