# Inserting image inside donut

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have made various donut charts using D3js and I need to insert one same image  inside the donut, but I can't figure out the way to achieve this. Can anyone help me with this? here's my JS code:

```
var data1 = [4,96];
var data2 = [1,99];
var data3 = [16,84];
var data4 = [12,88];
var data5 = [29,71];
var data6 = [15,85];
var data7 = [12,88];
var data8 = [10,90];

/* Reusable Drawing donut function*/

var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 100;

function drawDonut(dataa,divchart){
    var sym = "%"

    var color = ["#00338D","#BC204B"];

    var pie = d3.pie()
        .value(function(d) { return d })(dataa);

    var arc = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(radius - (radius/1.9));

    var labelArc = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 31)
        .innerRadius(radius - 31);

    var svg = d3.select(divchart)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" +60 + "," + 60 +")");

    var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
        .data(pie)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .data(color)
        .style("fill", function(d){return d});
    }

drawDonut(data1,"#pie1")
drawDonut(data2,"#pie2")
drawDonut(data3,"#pie3")
drawDonut(data4,"#pie4")
drawDonut(data5,"#pie5")
drawDonut(data6,"#pie6")
drawDonut(data7,"#pie7")
drawDonut(data8,"#pie8")
```

the image I want to insert is a svg one, this is the code:

```
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9
        L15.6,10.9z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13
        C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9
        L31.9,10.9z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6
        l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/>
</g>
```

can you help me decifer how to insert the image in the hole of the donut chart please? thank you

Comment: just add a `transform` attribute to the `g` from your example with the value `translate(200,200)` or whatever is the location you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store each `d` attribute as an individual constant and append the paths individually inside the `drawDonut` function, using the same group selection as parent.

However, a simpler solution is just saving everything as a single string...

```
var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-
    -2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7...etc...-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';
```

.... and appending it using the `html` method:

```
g.append("g").html(myGroup);
```

Caveat, lector: the `html()` method uses `innerHTML` internally. That won't work on SVG elements in old browsers. According to Amelia Bellamy-Royds, in her book *[Using SVG with CCS3 and HTML5](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=yWU6DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (2018):

> The latest version of web browsers even support `innerHTML` on SVG elements, but that is a recent addition to the core DOM specs.

For avoiding an unnecessary group inside another, you can also remove the `<g>` and `</g>` in the string.

Here is the demo:

```js
var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';

var data1 = [4, 96];
var data2 = [1, 99];
var data3 = [16, 84];
var data4 = [12, 88];
var data5 = [29, 71];
var data6 = [15, 85];
var data7 = [12, 88];
var data8 = [10, 90];

/* Reusable Drawing donut function*/

var width = 100,
  height = 100,
  radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2);

function drawDonut(dataa, divchart) {
  var sym = "%"

  var color = ["#00338D", "#BC204B"];

  var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d
    })(dataa);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

  var labelArc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 31)
    .innerRadius(radius - 31);

  var svg = d3.select(divchart)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 50 + ")");

  var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
    .data(pie)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .data(color)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d
    });

  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-15,-15) scale(0.6)")
    .html(myGroup);

}

drawDonut(data1, "#pie1")
drawDonut(data2, "#pie2")
drawDonut(data3, "#pie3")
drawDonut(data4, "#pie4")
drawDonut(data5, "#pie5")
drawDonut(data6, "#pie6")
drawDonut(data7, "#pie7")
drawDonut(data8, "#pie8")
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie2"></div>
<div id="pie3"></div>
<div id="pie4"></div>
<div id="pie5"></div>
<div id="pie6"></div>
<div id="pie7"></div>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie8"></div>
```

PS: There are some magic numbers in the transform. You can avoid them by calculating the group's size and initial drawing point.