# D3 append html element as child programmatically

Tags: d3.js

I have an in-house set of style rules that must use the following format:

```
.title span {
    many, many stylerules…
}
```

I am using d3 to parse from a csv that has titles and links. The end result is a title that also serves as a link to an external page. The relevant code is below:

```
...
var titleG = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + 0 + ')')
    .attr('class', 'title')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

var titleText = titleG
    .selectAll('text')
    .data([data], function(d) {
        return d.Event;
    });

titleText
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', width/2);

titleText
    .attr('y',100)
    .html(function(d) {return "<a href="+d.Url+">"+d.Event+"</a>"});

titleText
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .remove();

…
```

The trouble is I can't get my span to be appended as a child. I tried putting `.append('span')` in the middle (after `.enter()` and before `.exit()`) but nothing showed up I couldn't inspect element on it.

Referring back to the CSS code at the very top, the many style rules create an effect where the user hovers over a `.title` and a span that was `opacity:0` transitions to `opacity:1` revealing the innerHTML: "Click here to visit event page".

**Question:** How do I add `<span>`'s as a child of my `.title` elements that I'm creating programmatically with d3 so my style rules pick are applied correctly?

Comment: `<span>` is an html element, so you cannot add it to your svg `<g>` element. Can you use a `<tspan>` element instead?

Comment: why use `svg` as container? use one of your `div` tags and append `a` and `span` tags. Not good GUI design, that you have to hover over something invisible to get it show.

Comment: The main problem here is that `titleText` is an update selection, whose size is zero, unlike `titleText.enter()`, which is an enter selection. Therefore, you have to `merge()` the selections (or duplicate the code). Besides that, two minor problems: there is no `<span>` in SVG and `html()` sets the `innerHTML`, which will not work in an SVG as well.

Comment: @SteveR I think tspan could work. I hope this project isn't doomed, I overlooked the svg limitations...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I will try to experiment with merge, thanks for bringing that to my attention. For what it's worth, `html()` is working thus far, I created text `<a>`'s that have links, as per that line in my code. But it seems you are right about `<span>`s... I'm looking into tspans

Comment: @ArashHowaida `html()` may or may not work in XML, it depends. Just yesterday I wrote an answer here using `html()` for an SVG element... So, I should have said *"which may not work in an SVG as well"*. However, the API says *"SVG elements and other non-HTML elements do not support the innerHTML property, and thus are incompatible with selection.html"*, so it's better not always trusting it.

Comment: @ArashHowaida just for completeness, `html()` will work on modern browsers, have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51901976/5768908