# D3JS: Animate a 2 arc donut

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm kind of new to D3JS and I've made a 2 arc Donut (my data has only two values). I'm trying to figure out how to animate them so that the largest path get "self drawn" first and then the smallest one gets self drawn as well.

I know this can be achieved setting the start angle to 0 and then use the D3js attrTween() and play with the desired final angle. but since I can not declare the final angle by myself and it depends on the data, and due to my very little knowledge about djse I haven´t been able to achieve it.

This is my JS code:

```
var width = 100,
  height = 100,
  radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2);

function drawDonut(dataa, divchart) {
  var sym = "%"

  var color = ["#00338D", "#BC204B"];

  var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d
    })(dataa);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

  var labelArc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 31)
    .innerRadius(radius - 31);

  var svg = d3.select(divchart)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 50 + ")");

  var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
    .data(pie)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .data(color)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d
    });

  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-17,-17) scale(0.7)")
    .html(myGroup);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **data** from your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901976/inserting-image-inside-donut) and [attrTween](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636) as a reference, here's a snippet with the large-path-first animation applied to

```js
var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';

var data1 = [4, 96];
var data2 = [1, 99];
var data3 = [16, 84];
var data4 = [12, 88];
var data5 = [29, 71];
var data6 = [15, 85];
var data7 = [12, 88];
var data8 = [10, 90];

var width = 100,
  height = 100,
  radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2);

function drawDonut(data, divchart) {
  var sym = "%"

  var color = ["#BC204B","#00338D"];

 // sort data
  data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
  var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d
    })(data);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

  var labelArc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 31)
    .innerRadius(radius - 31);

  var svg = d3.select(divchart)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 50 + ")");

  var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
    .data(pie)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color[i];
    })
    .transition().delay(function (d, i) { return i*800}).duration(800)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween)  

  function arcTween(d) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle, d.endAngle);
    return function (t) {
     d.endAngle = i(t);
      return arc(d);
    }
 }

  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-17,-17) scale(0.7)")
    .html(myGroup);    
}

drawDonut(data1, "#pie1")
drawDonut(data2, "#pie2")
drawDonut(data3, "#pie3")
drawDonut(data4, "#pie4")
drawDonut(data5, "#pie5")
drawDonut(data6, "#pie6")
drawDonut(data7, "#pie7")
drawDonut(data8, "#pie8")
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie2"></div>
<div id="pie3"></div>
<div id="pie4"></div>
<div id="pie5"></div>
<div id="pie6"></div>
<div id="pie7"></div>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie8"></div>
```

**Relevant changes:**

1. AttrTween function

   ```
   function arcTween(d) {
     var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle, d.endAngle);
     return function (t) {
       d.endAngle = i(t);
       return arc(d);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use the above for the paths along with a delay in the transition which btw is used to animate the paths in sequence.

   ```
   g.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
       return color[i];
    })
    .transition().delay(function (d, i) { return i*800}).duration(800)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);
   ```
3. Sorted data in a descending order to draw the largest arc first.

   ```
   // sort data
   data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by [Shashank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51934334/9938317) I like to propose a modification

- do not sort the `data` because the order looks important (d[0] == man, d[1] == woman) and the arcs are colored in order

  ```
  // sort data
  //data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
  ```
- the pie generator should also not sort the data based on value

  ```
  var pie = d3.pie()
    .sortValues(null) // both null means NO sort
    .value(function(d) {
      return d
    })(data);
  ```
- in Shashanks answer both parts are animated with `easeCubic` and each part (small or large) takes 800ms. To get a constant angular speed animation we must set the delay and duration based on the `startAngle` and the `endAngle` of the part. And the transition must be set to `easeLinear`. For the demo I have set the complete animation to 5000ms.

  ```
  var msecPerRad = 5000 / (2*Math.PI);
  g.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .delay(function (d) { return d.startAngle * msecPerRad;})
    .duration(function (d) { return (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) * msecPerRad;})
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);
  ```

Example with Linear easing

```js
var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';

var data1 = [50, 50];
var data2 = [70, 30];
var data3 = [16, 84];
var data4 = [12, 88];
var data5 = [29, 71];
var data6 = [15, 85];
var data7 = [12, 88];
var data8 = [10, 90];

var width = 100,
  height = 100,
  radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2);

function drawDonut(data, divchart) {
  var sym = "%"

  var color = ["#BC204B","#00338D"];

  // sort data
  //data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
  var pie = d3.pie()
    .sortValues(null) // both null means NO sort
    .value(function(d) {
      return d
    })(data);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

  var labelArc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 31)
    .innerRadius(radius - 31);

  var svg = d3.select(divchart)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 50 + ")");

  var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
    .data(pie)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

  var msecPerRad = 5000 / (2*Math.PI);
  g.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .delay(function (d) { return d.startAngle * msecPerRad;})
    .duration(function (d) { return (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) * msecPerRad;})
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  function arcTween(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle, d.endAngle);
    return function (t) {
     d.endAngle = i(t);
      return arc(d);
    }
  }

  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-17,-17) scale(0.7)")
    .html(myGroup);    
}

drawDonut(data1, "#pie1")
drawDonut(data2, "#pie2")
drawDonut(data3, "#pie3")
drawDonut(data4, "#pie4")
drawDonut(data5, "#pie5")
drawDonut(data6, "#pie6")
drawDonut(data7, "#pie7")
drawDonut(data8, "#pie8")
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie2"></div>
<div id="pie3"></div>
<div id="pie4"></div>
<div id="pie5"></div>
<div id="pie6"></div>
<div id="pie7"></div>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie8"></div>
```

If you want the complete angle animation performed with an `easeCubic` it takes little more math. The main reason is that both arc segments are independent trasitions. This should work for more then 2 arc segments.

It only works for **monotone increasing** easing functions, not for things like bounce, elastic and back(in/out).

```
  function easeInverse(ease) {
    return function(e) {
      var min = 0, max = 1;
      while (max - min > 1e-3) {
        var mid = (max + min) * 0.5;
        emid = ease(mid);
        if (emid > e) { max = mid; }
        else { min = mid; }
      }
      return max;
    }
  }
  var inverseCubic = easeInverse(d3.easeCubic);
  var oneOver2Pi = 1.0 / (2*Math.PI);
  var total_msec = 5000;

  g.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .delay(function (d) { return total_msec * inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi);})
    .duration(function (d) { return total_msec * (inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi) - inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi));})
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  function arcTween(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi), inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi));
    return function (t) {
      d.endAngle = 2*Math.PI*d3.easeCubic(i(t));
      return arc(d);
    }
  }
```

Example with Cubic easing for the full circle angle.

```js
var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';

var data1 = [50, 50];
var data2 = [70, 30];
var data3 = [16, 84];
var data4 = [12, 88];
var data5 = [29, 71];
var data6 = [15, 85];
var data7 = [12, 88];
var data8 = [10, 90];

var width = 100,
  height = 100,
  radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2);

function drawDonut(data, divchart) {
  var sym = "%"

  var color = ["#BC204B","#00338D"];

  // sort data
  //data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
  var pie = d3.pie()
    .sortValues(null) // both null means NO sort
    .value(function(d) {
      return d
    })(data);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

  var labelArc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 31)
    .innerRadius(radius - 31);

  var svg = d3.select(divchart)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 50 + ")");

  var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
    .data(pie)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

  function easeInverse(ease) {
    return function(e) {
      var min = 0, max = 1;
      while (max - min > 1e-3) {
        var mid = (max + min) * 0.5;
        emid = ease(mid);
        if (emid > e) { max = mid; }
        else { min = mid; }
      }
      return max;
    }
  }
  var inverseCubic = easeInverse(d3.easeCubic);
  var oneOver2Pi = 1.0 / (2*Math.PI);
  var total_msec = 5000;

  g.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .delay(function (d) { return total_msec * inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi);})
    .duration(function (d) { return total_msec * (inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi) - inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi));})
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  function arcTween(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi), inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi));
    return function (t) {
      d.endAngle = 2*Math.PI*d3.easeCubic(i(t));
      return arc(d);
    }
  }

  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-17,-17) scale(0.7)")
    .html(myGroup);    
}

drawDonut(data1, "#pie1")
drawDonut(data2, "#pie2")
drawDonut(data3, "#pie3")
drawDonut(data4, "#pie4")
drawDonut(data5, "#pie5")
drawDonut(data6, "#pie6")
drawDonut(data7, "#pie7")
drawDonut(data8, "#pie8")
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie2"></div>
<div id="pie3"></div>
<div id="pie4"></div>
<div id="pie5"></div>
<div id="pie6"></div>
<div id="pie7"></div>
<div id="pie1"></div>
<div id="pie8"></div>
```